# How to stretch an image so that it fits the entire screen in javafx

Tags: java, image, javafx

Relevant code

```
package whowantstobeamillionairetriviagame;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.scene.layout.Background;
import javafx.scene.layout.BackgroundImage;
import javafx.scene.layout.BackgroundPosition;
import javafx.scene.layout.BackgroundRepeat;
import javafx.scene.layout.BackgroundSize;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class WhoWantsToBeAMillionaireTriviaGame extends Application 
{   
@Override
public void start(Stage startingStage) throws Exception
{    
    Image backgroundColor = new Image("http://www.sonomare.com/darkblue_background_rot_180.jpg");

    BackgroundSize backgroundSize = new BackgroundSize(100, 100, true, true, true, false);
    BackgroundImage backgroundImage = new BackgroundImage(backgroundColor, BackgroundRepeat.NO_REPEAT, BackgroundRepeat.NO_REPEAT, BackgroundPosition.CENTER, backgroundSize);

    StackPane background = new StackPane();
    background.setBackground(new Background(backgroundImage));

    Scene menuScene = new Scene(background);
    startingStage.setScene(menuScene);
    startingStage.setFullScreen(true);
    startingStage.show();
}

public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    launch(args);
}
}
```

I'm asking because using repeat will cause the picture to repeat over and over the x and y axis so it can fit the whole entire screen. Using no repeat will leave a bunch of white spaces all around it. Round, Space and setting the stage to full screen doesn't help either. What can i do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the background size as cover.

From the docs

> the size might be defined with cover = true, meaning the image should be stretched to cover the entire rendering surface of the Region.

The definition for [BackgroundSize](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/layout/BackgroundSize.html#BackgroundSize-double-double-boolean-boolean-boolean-boolean-) becomes

```
BackgroundSize backgroundSize = new BackgroundSize(100, 100, true, true, true, true);
```

Comment: Thank you sir, it looks a lot better.